# Display the order id and order date in WooCommerce My account downloads

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, download, orders

I want to display the order ID, order date and product image in the My Account download page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-product', 'display_product_image_on_account_downloads' );
function display_product_image_on_account_downloads( $download ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) ) return;

    if ( $download['product_id'] > 0 ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $download['product_id'] ); 
        $image   = $product->get_image( array(324, 194) ); // The product image
        $order_id = $order->get_id(); // The order id

        if ( $download['product_url'] ) {
            echo $image . '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['product_url'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $download['product_name'] ) . '</a>';
        echo '<p>' . esc_html( $order_id ) . '</p>';
            echo '<p>' . esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) . '</p>'; 
        } else {
            echo $image . esc_html( $download['product_name'] );
        }
    }
}
```

The product image is displayed, but the order ID and order date do not display properly.
Is there any way of achieving this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, `woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-product` is an action hook and the variable `$order` is not defined in your code.

Use instead this revisited code version:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-product', 'display_product_image_on_account_downloads' );
function display_product_image_on_account_downloads( $download ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) ) return;

    if ( $download['product_id'] > 0 ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $download['product_id'] ); 
        $image   = $product->get_image( array(324, 194) ); // The product image

        if ( $download['product_url'] ) {
            echo $image . '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['product_url'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $download['product_name'] ) . '</a>';

            // Here you get the order ID
            if ( $download['order_id'] > 0 ) {
                // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
                $order = wc_get_order( $download['order_id'] );

                echo '<p>' . esc_attr( $download['order_id'] ) . '</p>'; 
                echo '<p>' . esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) . '</p>'; 
        } else {
            echo $image . esc_html( $download['product_name'] );
        }
    }
}
```

It should work now.

Answer (score -1):

I carefully check your code and realized it has some problems. So you can use these version:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-product', 'display_product_image_order_info_on_account_downloads', 10, 2 );
function display_product_image_order_info_on_account_downloads( $download, $item ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) ) return;

    if ( $download['product_id'] > 0 ) {
        $product    = wc_get_product( $download['product_id'] );
        $image      = $product->get_image( array( 324, 194 ) ); // The product image
        $order_id   = $item->get_order_id(); // Get the order ID from the $item object
        $order_date = $item->get_order()->get_date_created(); // Get the order date from the $item object

        if ( $download['product_url'] ) {
            echo $image . '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['product_url'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $download['product_name'] ) . '</a>';
            echo '<p>' . esc_html( $order_id ) . '</p>';
            echo '<p>' . esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order_date ) ) . '</p>'; 
        } else {
            echo $image . esc_html( $download['product_name'] );
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it on your function.php on your child-theme.